# gridview is refreshing result rows when clicked on the select command column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to view one of the result as a report in the report viewer by clicking on the select command in the 1st column. But the other rows are refreshing and showing different rows when the report is displayed below the grid in a report viewer. i don't want the results to change when i select a particular row..

Comment: Do you do the databinding in page load?

Comment: yes i am doing the data binding in the page load

Answer (score 0):

use 2 updatePanels. Put the gridview in the first updatepanel and set the triggers to be never. In the second update panel put the details gridview and set the triggers to condistional  and add the trigger for the click for the select from the first gridview.